# how to switch between 2 lists in angular

Tags: angular

i have a contact list that i want to display when the user click on search icon

and i have a search list that i want to display when  the user start typing

lsit.component.html

```
    <app-recent-chat-list appHideElement [hideIf]="showEmptyState 
        || showContactList || showSearchList"></app-recent-chat-list>

        <app-contact-search-result-list *ngIf="showSearchList"></app- 
        contact-search-result-list>

         <app-contact-list *ngIf="showContactList" ></app-contact- 
          list>
```

list.component.ts

```
    handleDisplayingContactList() {
   // Subscribe to the openContactList subject
   this.subscription = 
   this.contactSearchService.openContactList.subscribe(
     openContactList => {
      // display contact list when the search icon has been clicked, else hide it
      if (openContactList === true) {
         this.showContactList = true;
      } else {
         this.showContactList= false;
      }
    });
}

handleDisplayingSearchResults() {
   // Subscribe to the openContactList subject
   this.subscription = this.contactSearchService.openSearchResults.subscribe(
      openSearchResults => {
        // display search list when start typing, else hide it 
        if (openSearchResults === true) {
          this.showSearchList= true;
        } else {
          this.showSearchList = false;
        }
      });
}
```

searchingtext.component.ts

```
updateSearchModel() {
    this.contactSearchService.openSearchResults.next(true);
}
```

Comment: your list.component.html is missing

Answer (score 0):

The most `rx`ic way to achive that is so called "higher order observable" - an observable of observables: `Observable<Observable<ContactList>>`. Depeing upon user's behavior, you'd have to `next(openContactList)` or `next(openSearchResults)`.

Consider using `swtichMap()` to avoid race conditions.

---

The second - and less elegant, but still `rx`ic way - to achieve that is with help of `iif()`, which takes as input a predicate and two observables: one for `true` case, other one - for `false`.

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: @reand, bind your `component.html` to a single `constacts$: Observable<ContactList>` and implement switching behavior using standartd and well-documented operators I've mentioned above.  Once agrain - you'll get a stream of streams (so called "higher order observable" - yet another well-known recognized term).